# Confirm age before entering a category

Tags: magento-1.8, php, php-5.4, prototype-js, html

I want customers to answer a question before entering a category in Magento 1.8.1. For example, I want to ask a confirmation question like "Are you 18 or older?" if a customer clicked on a adult stuff category; he/she would allowed in if they answer yes.

I found this code and put it in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml` but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var conf = confirm('are you 18 or more ?');
        if(conf == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is my view.phtml : http://www.4shared.com/file/M9p259fvba/view.html

Which line should I put that code exactly?

Comment: isn't there any one to answer?
please i need help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bail out from already opened catalog you want to use template/catalog/product/list.phtml and template/catalog/product/new.phtml

If you want to do it correctly, i.e. BEFORE opening the folder, you might want to look into template/catalog/navigation.phtml (those templates render left and top navigation menu).

Comment: what should i replace with `http://google.com` ?
@Pronto